# How to install Fatrat

Tags: download-manager, fatrat

Fatrat is not available in the official repository of Ubuntu. How to install it? What dependencies are required?

> Official Website - http://fatrat.dolezel.info/
>
> Official Github  - https://github.com/LubosD/fatrat

Comment: anachronism--question is dated November 2015 and it's about Ubuntu 2018.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I edited the question recently to ask about the instructions for installing it in 18.04

Comment: @Lincity - It is not clear what info dates from 2015, what from 2018, what is current (readers shouldn't delve into the edit history).
It would be great if you could post whatever you already found as of today, duly dated. E.g., "Fatrat was available for 20.04 but...", "I could compile from source but...", or anything else you could have tried.

Comment: FYI: given that there have been **no updates** to the code for fatrat since 2018, it is possible the software is unmaintained.  As such, there may not be a way to compile this for the modern 22.04 OS if the librares that fatrat needs are outdated.  Just making a note about that, especially since the main fatrat website is dead it suggests a 'dead project'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Good News:

I, successfully, built the [FatRat Download Manager](https://github.com/LubosD/fatrat) from source on **Ubuntu 22.04** with **curl** support which should enable **HTTP(S)**, **FTP(S)** and **SFTP** downloads. However I found two source files with deprecated / outdated code and had to empty their contents in order for the build to succeed. These two files are `src/util/BalloonTip.cpp` and `src/util/moc_BalloonTip.cpp` and I didn't notice any missing functionality after the build. The application worked fully *(with the system tray applet)* on both **Wayland** and **X11**.

#### The Not Good News:

However, the bittorrent download support was far too complicated to bring back to life so I gave up on it, but I included all its needed up to date dependencies to the "install dependencies" step below anyway.

---

### The Build Steps:

- Install dependencies like so:

  ```
  sudo apt install build-essential cmake qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev pkg-config libtorrent-rasterbar2.0 libboost-dev libboost-date-time1.74.0 libboost-date-time-dev libtorrent-dev libboost-serialization-dev libqt5svg5-dev libtorrent-rasterbar-dev libboost-system-dev qtwebengine5-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev qt6-base-dev gcc-12 git
  ```
- Then clone the FatRat source from GitHub and `cd` into the directory like so:

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/LubosD/fatrat && cd fatrat/
  ```
- Then empty two outdated files in the source like so:

  ```
  > src/util/BalloonTip.cpp && > src/util/moc_BalloonTip.cpp
  ```
- Then prepare with `curl` support like so:

  ```
  sudo cmake . -DWITH_CURL=ON
  ```
- Then make and install like so:

  ```
  sudo make && sudo make install
  ```

Answer (score 10):

You can compile and install fatrat from source as shown in following steps.

First You need to install following libraries as shown in  exact following sequence.

**Note:**  Here sequence matters.

```
sudo apt install build-essential cmake qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev pkg-config libtorrent-rasterbar9 libtorrent-rasterbar-dbg libboost1.62-dev libboost-date-time1.62.0 libboost-date-time1.62-dev libboost-date-time1.62-dev libtorrent-dev libboost-serialization1.62-dev libboost1.62-dev

sudo apt install libqt5svg5-dev 
sudo apt install libtorrent-rasterbar-dev libtorrent-rasterbar-dbg libboost-system-dev  libboost-system1.65-dev  libboost1.65-dev
sudo apt install libboost-date-time1.65-dev
```

Once required libraries are installed. You can compile source from fatrat git repository and install.

```
git clone https://github.com/LubosD/fatrat && cd fatrat/
sudo cmake . -DWITH_BITTORRENT=ON -DWITH_SFTP=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
sudo make && sudo make install
```

To Enable downloading with HTTP links in Fatrat, You need to install following dependencies along above dependencies and use extra switch `WITH_CURL`.

```
sudo apt install qtwebengine5-dev
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Compile Source code with extra switch `WITH_CURL`.

```
sudo cmake . -DWITH_BITTORRENT=ON -DWITH_SFTP=ON -DWITH_CURL=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
sudo make && sudo make install
```

All steps have been tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thanks this works but cannot download HTTP links only torrent files. I assume CURL needs to be enabled for that. Is there a way to enable CURL?

Comment: You can do it with using WITH_CURL switch while compiling source code.

Comment: Dependency problems and compilation errors if I enable the WITH_CURL switch. Anyway I'm awarding you the bounty because technically I specified using the source code and finding dependencies and didn't specify CURL.

Comment: You need to install two more dependencies for it and compile source code again.  Edited answer for  solution.

Answer (score 5):

## Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

I tried to make search in all PPAs for `fatrat`:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=fatrat

And got the following PPA: [`ppa:alex-p/notesalexp-bionic`](https://launchpad.net/~alex-p/+archive/ubuntu/notesalexp-bionic?field.series_filter=bionic).

You can add it to system and install `fatrat` version *1.2.0+git20180628-1ppa1~bionic1*:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alex-p/notesalexp-bionic
sudo apt-get install fatrat
```

It will be installed in *Internet* category, it great and has tray icon (tested on MATE):

[image: FatRat on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS]

Comment: Shouldn't these be the accepted answer? It seems much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

## ubuntu 15.10

This is what I gather from the download and installation pages:

```
sudo apt-get install libgloox-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libpion-dev libqt5svg5-dev libqt5svg5-private-dev libboost-date-time1.58-dev qttools5-dev-tools qttools5-dev-tools libtorrent-rasterbar-dev cmake git
git clone git://git.dolezel.info/fatrat.git
cd fatrat
cmake . -DWITH_BITTORRENT=ON -DWITH_SFTP=ON -DWITH_CURL=ON
make
sudo make install
fatrat
```

Comment: There is a error which I have included in my question.

Comment: Well, it says on the download page that the program needs QT. So you need to install that too. See here: http://www.qt.io/download/

Comment: I get a different error now.

Comment: You keep changing the subject of the question, which does not help future posters. If you need, ask a separate question. However, the error above clearly states what is wrong: you need the `libtorrent-rasterbar` package. A tiny bit of googling tells me that you can download that [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libtorrent/files/libtorrent/).

Answer (score 1):

## ubuntu 15.10

You can install it simply by adding this PPA first:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

Then install using:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fatrat
```

Answer (score 0):

## ubuntu 15.10

You can install FatRat Download manager from Ubuntu Software Center,It is available in Ubuntu repository.There is no need to add unnecessary PPA for this.